# c# Memory on Nested Callbacks inside Action

Tags: c#

So, i have this piece of code:

```
 public void MovementTick()
    {
        if(MovementBehaviour != null)
        {
            MovementBehaviour.PerformMovement(this);
            GameScheduler.Schedule(new SchedulerTask(MovementDelay)
            {
                Task = () =>
                {
                    MovementTick();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

This is to keep the scheduler running the monster tasks. However, since this is a nested call on MovementTick() will this cause memory problems somehow ? Is this code safe to use ? Should this be calling outside functions not to nest the MovementTick method ?

Would apreciate any help

Comment: I think you should use timer and subscribe to it's ontick event. Then just call `MovementBehaviour.PerformMovement(this)` from the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a timer tick event.

```
Timer timer { get; set; }

 void Start () 
 {
     timer = new Timer();
     timer.Interval = Timespan.FromMilliseconds(100);
     timer.Elapsed +=TimerTick;

     timer.Start();

 }

 void TimerTick(object o, EventArgs e)
 {
     MovementBehaviour?.PerformMovement(this); 
 }
```